# PIG: Compute max distance between pairs of latitudes and longitudes

Tags: python, apache-pig

I have a bag in pig that has been grouped by key and whose values are latitude and longitude. I want to compute the max distance between any two (lat, long) pairs for every key; if there is less then two then the output should be 0.

For example, if my bag was

```
{(1): (1.1, 1.1),
 (1): (2.1, 2.1),
 (1): (3.1, 3.1),
 (2): (1.1, 1.1)
}
```

my answer would be

```
{(1): 314 (km)
 (2): 0
}
```

The equation to compute the distance between two (lat, long) pairs is:

```
(((lat1 - lat2) * pi() * 3959 / 180)^2 + ((long1 - long2) * 2 * pi() * 3959 * cos(((lat2 + lat1) / 2) * .0174533) / 360)^2)^(1/2)
```

Is there an easy way to create a python udf to do this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I think of:

1. FLATTEN the bag. This would generate tuples (in your example) with

   (1,1.1,1.1)
   (1,2.1,2.1)
   (1,3.1,3.1)
   (2,1.1,1.1)
2. Perform the step above TWICE, giving the resulting relations two different names: r1 and r2.
3. JOIN the r1 and r2, by the key field. This will create a cartesian product for each key

JOIN r1 by key, r2 by key

This will result in

```
(1,1.1,1.1,1,1.1,1.1)
(1,1.1,1.1,1,2.1,2.1)
(1,1.1,1.1,1,3.1,3.1)
(1,2.1,2.1,1,1.1,1.1)
(1,2.1,2.1,1,2.1,2.1)
(1,2.1,2.1,1,3.1,3.1)
(1,3.1,3.1,1,1.1,1.1)
(1,3.1,3.1,1,2.1,2.1)
(1,3.1,3.1,1,3.1,3.1)
(2,1.1,1.1,2,1.1,1.1)
```

This list contains all the possible pairs for each key. As a bonus, for keys with only one coordinate, you also get a pair of that coordinate with itself.

3. Use the HaversineDistInMiles UDF from datafu 
   http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/geo/HaversineDistInMiles.html

to calculate the distance between each pair of coordinates. For pairs which are the same coordinate, you would get distance == 0.

(datafu is a great package of utility UDFs from LinkedIn. Read about it here: https://datafu.incubator.apache.org)

4. group by key, and generate the MAX(distance) for each key. This will give you the maximal distance in Miles. Multiply by 1.6093 to get the distance in KM.

Assuming your file looks like this:

```
1   {(1.1,1.1),(2.1,2.1),(3.1,3.1)}
2   {(1.1,1.1)}
```

use this pig script:

```
register '/path/to/datafu-1.2.0.jar';
a = LOAD 'pigcoords.tsv' using PigStorage() as (A1:int, B1:bag{T:tuple(longitude:double, latitude:double)});
b = foreach a generate A1, FLATTEN(B1);
c = foreach a generate A1, FLATTEN(B1);
d = foreach (join b by A1, c by A1) generate $0..;
op = FOREACH d GENERATE b::A1 as key, datafu.pig.geo.HaversineDistInMiles(b::B1::latitude, b::B1::longitude, c::B1::latitude, c::B1::longitude) as distance;
res = FOREACH (group op by key) generate MAX(op.distance)*1.6093;
dump res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my github repo:
https://github.com/csabakecskemeti/geo_clustering/tree/master/src/main/java/kecso/geotools/geodistance

This is a java UDF for geo distance calculation. You can use this to calculate the distance on the pairn than apply a MAX function. I hope this helps.